# jquery document.ready function isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The document ready function isn't working for me, but it worked just the day before. Also, no other jQuery function works in that file but it did a couple of days ago. can somebody help?

here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //does not log ready
  console.log('ready');
  //animation for slides
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
  //this does work
  setInterval(function() {

    $('#slideshow > div:first')
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
  }, 4000);
  //end of animation
  $('nav ul div').hover(function() {
    $('.aMain').addClass('expand');
  }, function() {
    $('.aMain').removeClass('expand');
  });

  $('#a').hover(function() {
    $('.aMain').addClass('expand');

  }, function() {
    $('.aMain').removeClass('expand');
  });
  //this doesnt log click inside the function
  $('.subA', '.aNav').click(function() {
    console.log('click');
    console.log($(this).get(0).id);
    //sessionStorage.setItem("catagory", $(this).get(0).id); -> commented to not throw error on SO

  });
  //$('#thead').text(sessionStorage.getItem("catagory")); -> commented to not throw error on SO
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alpert Cooks - Cook and Share</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Logo.png" id="logo" alt="" href="AlpertCooks/index.html" /></a>


    <nav id="nav">

      <ul>

        <li><a class="anav" href="recipeList.php">מנות ראשונות</a></li>
        <li><a id="a" class="anav">מנות עיקריות</a></li>


        <li><a id="vegeterian" class="anav" href="recipeList.php">צמחוני</a></li>
        <li><a id="salads" class="anav" href="recipeList.php">סלטים</a></li>
        <li><a id="deserts" class="anav" href="recipeList.php">קינוחים</a></li>
        <li><a id="speciala" href="recipeUpload.php">העלו מתכון שלכם</a></li>
        <div class="aMain">

          <li><a id="meat" href="recipeList.php" class="subA">בשר</a></li>
          <li><a id="bread" href="recipeList.php" class="subA">פחמימות</a></li>
          <li><a id="fish" href="recipeList.php" class="subA">דגים</a></li>
          <li><a id="milk" href="recipeList.php" class="subA">דברי חלב</a></li>
          <li><a class="subA">אחר</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>


    </nav>

  </header>
  <main id="main">


    <div id="slideshow">
      <div>
        <div class="title">
          <h2 class="h2">פסטה</h2>

          <img id="line" src="images/decorative-clipart-fancy-3.png" alt="" /></div>
        <img id="slides" src="images/d87c1237-c3e2-401a-b26b-9afc323e503f.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="title">
          <h2 class="h2">פירה</h2>

          <img id="line" src="images/decorative-clipart-fancy-3.png" alt="" /></div>
        <img id="slides" src="images/ab7c95c8-781c-4d09-93f2-d484a95cde2d.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>

  <footer>


  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

I added comments inside the code so you can see which functions are working and which ones are not. All the hover functions are working.

Comment: Your first `//this is not working` comment is above the whole block of code. Which part isn't working? The "ready" text in the console? Also, do you have any errors displayed in the said console?

Comment: the function in document ready

Comment: Your whole code is inside `document.ready`.

Comment: I know. why is it not working

Comment: @INTODAN, running the snippet here logs 'ready'

Comment: I love when code just stops working..... So what did you change? Code seems to be running the fade in/out

Comment: i know, so mabye it is just the click function that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

As the JS snippet runs normally, assuming no network problems, Google CDN's delivery of the jQuery script will is also assumed to happen normally.

The issue can be pinpointed to the part where the JS file is imported to the HTML file, which is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

You will want to check your browser's devtools/inspector's Network tab to see if you are getting a 404 response/error for fetching this script. If so, the problem has been correctly identified, which is that the javascript file is not available at the location `js/scripts.js`. Verify the location/address of the javascript file to ensure that the scripted is imported correctly to the HTML file.